# code first many to many set name of table

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I'm new to code first and derived from DB Context. Here is a excerpt of my Model.

```
[Table("pm_Material")]
public class Material
{
    public Material()
    {
        this.ProductionStepLogs = new HashSet<ProductionStepLog>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
    public int MaterialTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal CostRate { get; set; }

    public virtual MaterialType MaterialType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductionStepLog> ProductionStepLogs { get; set; }
}

[Table("pm_ProductionStepLog")]
public class ProductionStepLog
{
    public ProductionStepLog()
    {
        this.Materials = new HashSet<Material>();
    }

    [Key]
    public System.Guid ProductionStepLogId { get; set; }
    public int ProductionStepId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> BeginStep { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndStep { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductionStep ProductionStep { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Material> Materials { get; set; }
}
```

The DB creation works fine, but I want to specify the name of the auto-generated many-to-many table "ProductionStepLogMaterials" using [Table("pm_ProductionStepLogMaterials")].

Is this possible?

Comment: was it helpfull for you?

Comment: @NSGaga, Yes, just the name.

Comment: @MikroDel, I will test it and will response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override your `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` of your own DBContext class like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
   modelBuilder.Entity<Material>()
     .HasMany(a => a.ProductionStepLog)
     .WithMany(a => a.Material)
     .Map(x =>
     {
        x.ToTable("NameOfYourTable");
        x.MapLeftKey("MaterialId");
        x.MapRightKey("ProductionStepLogId");
     });
}
```

Comment: Can't this be achieved with `DataAnnotations` too?

Comment: @e.campver - I think not - cause `DataAnnotations` is some kind of subset of the whole `Entity Framework` functionality. As for today you can use `DataAnnotations` for the most common scenarios, but not for all of them

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is impossible with Data Annotations, but it is possible with configuration fluent API:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<E1Type>()
            .HasMany(e1 => e1.Collection)
            .WithMany(e2 => e2.Collection)
            .Map(config => config.ToTable("MyTable"));
    }
```